# How can I detect if a user profile in Windows is a roaming profile?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, roaming-profile

I have a user who is having some issues. In order for me to resolve it I need to know if he is on a roaming profile or not. I believe he is but I want to confirm it. What are some signs that will tell me?

Also he is using Windows XP Pro and we are on an Active Directory domain in Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to the user's machine, go to System Properties -> Advanced -> User profiles; there you will see if it's a local or roaming profile.

You can also have a look at the user's profile settings in Active Directory (they are in the user account's properties).

Comment: +1 - There isnt much more you can say for this one :)